# Convert a submat from RGB to GRAY OpenCV

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I'm working on an android program that should detect a face in a live video, and convert the facial region to gray-scale. I successfully manage to create a border around the detected facial region, and using the function shown below, i've managed to create a submat that shows the face on the top left of the main Mat. My plan is to convert this submat to gray-scale and then place it over the actual face, unless someone has a more efficient approach?

The code for the submat can be seen below. When i add the line:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba2,mRgba2,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

There are no errors, but the stretched face on the topleft corner isn't shown. I figured this is because mRgba2 is now a different type, so i tried adding

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba2,mRgba2,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba2,mRgba2,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
```

to convert mRgba2 back to RGB but this didn't work either.

```
public void processFrame(Mat face) { 

    Mat mRgba2 = face.clone();
    Imgproc.resize(face, mRgba2, new Size (400, 200));
    Mat submat = mRgba.submat(0, 200, 0, 400);
    mRgba2.copyTo(submat);
}
```

[image]

Comment: please post you error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use in-place conversion

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba2,mRgba2,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

instead try to use a second variable:

```
Mat mGray;
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba2,mGray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

But are you sure that RGB is the right type? Your variable is named Rgba, so maybe you'll need `Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried using RGBA instead but that didnt work either. Addind a new variable also doesn't have any affect :/

Comment: please add your complete relevant code and the error messages to your question

Comment: I added the code to pastebin on the link provided. The onCameraFrame method is called every time a new frame is called, and the process frame attempts to create and convert a submat to grayscale from rgb.

Comment: I Managed, you were right i was using RGB instead of RGBA!! The solution for anyone seeing this in the future is you have to convert the Mat back to RGBA before the .copyTo part!